# regex for replacing _ with - in all URLs

Tags: regex

I have lots of URLs in WordPress pages that have **_** (underscores) like this:
https://wpg.meditationyoga.in/Peace_research_studies/
and need to replace **_** with **-** (dash) to get this:
https://wpg.meditationyoga.in/Peace-research-studies/

but have to use regex that only is making this replacement in URLs and not for example in other elements like id=”attachment_1076″ or id=”grad_table”

I'm using Search Regex plugin.
What is the regex for the above replacements?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure but I think by looking at the [plugin](https://searchregex.com/) it supports 'PHP' meaning you could try a pattern like:

```
(?:https?\S+?(?=_)|\G(?!^))(?:[^ _]*)\K_
```

- `(?:` - Open 1st Non-capturing group.

  - `https?` - Match 'http' literally with an optional 's'.
  - `\S+?` - Any non-whitespace character, in a lazy match.
  - `(?=_)` - Positive lookahead for an underscore.
  - `|` - Alternation/OR.
  - `\G(?!^)` - Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group.

  - `[^ _]*` - Match zero or more characters other than space or underscore.
  - `)` - Close 2nd non capture group.
- `\K_` - Reset the match buffer and match an underscore.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xbtFP1/3)